# Touchpad not working on Lenovo Yoga Slim 7

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I have a lenovo running 20.04 and new to linux, everything else is running but the touch pad has stopped working.

I ran

```
xinput list
```

and can see the touch pad in the list itself

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 1bcf:08a0 Mouse                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 1bcf:08a0 Consumer Control            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA2B5A:00 06CB:CDB0 Mouse               id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA2B5A:00 06CB:CDB0 Touchpad            id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 1bcf:08a0 Keyboard                    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 1bcf:08a0 Consumer Control            id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So i then ran

```
xinput enable 16
```

and nothing is working, I did look at other suggestions but nothing for this build

If anyone has any experience or has done a fix please give me a little hand

Comment: Was it woking and has stopped or has it never worked?

Comment: sorry, yes it worked and then stopped

Comment: Then there is a good chance that a update changed the kernel from 5.4 to 5.8 A lot of issues around 5.8 at this time. You will need to during boot go into Ubuntu advanced and choose the 5.4 kernel to verify that.

Comment: Right so change the Kernal version, ok I will see how thats done, Thank you